# Read data with WIN1251 encoding from Firebird database via powershell

Tags: powershell, odbc, firebird, firebird2.5

I have database with tables in WIN1251 encoding. When I read data from tables then all the text that is in Cyrillic are shown as unknown symbols.  This is the code I use:

```
function Get-ODBC-Data {
    param([string]$query = $(throw 'query is required.'))
    $conn = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection
    $connStr = "Driver=Firebird/Interbase(r) driver;Server=localhost;Port=3050;Database=C:\Users\user\Desktop\B52.GDB;Uid=SYSDBA;Pwd=masterkey;CHARSET=WIN1251"
    $conn.ConnectionString = $connStr
    $conn.open
    $cmd = new-object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand($query, $conn)
    $cmd.CommandTimeout = 15
    $ds = New-Object system.Data.DataSet
    $da = New-Object system.Data.odbc.odbcDataAdapter($cmd)
    [void]$da.fill($ds)
    $ds.Tables[0] 
    $conn.close()
}

$query = @"
    SELECT name FROM contact;
"@

$result = Get-ODBC-Data -query $query
$customers = @();
foreach ($row in $result) {
    if (-not($null -eq $row.name)) {
        $customers += $row.name;
    }
}

$customers
```

Comment: What tool are you using that shows the Cyrillic symbols incorrectly? Are you trying to change encoding from Win1251 to something more readable?  [Try this answer to change encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42884025/c-sharp-encode-connection-string-from-win1251-to-utf8-and-back). I can help if you have difficulty converting C# code to Powershell.

Comment: Do the columns in the database have an explicit character set? If so, have you tried specifying UTF8 as the connection character set instead?

Comment: Also, have you tried the Firebird ADO.net provider instead of the ODBC driver?

Comment: Thanks, @MarkRotteveel changing charset to UTF8 helped. How did that work? Could you please create an answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: There are two options: your database has columns with character set NONE, and the data was actually in UTF8, and not in WIN1251, or the ODBC driver combined with Powershell doesn't handle strings in a different character set properly (I think powershell is utf-8 by default).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try specifying the connection character set as UTF8 instead of WIN1251.

This will only work if your database really contains data in WIN1251 and those columns have WIN1251 as their explicit character set, if those columns have character set NONE (or `NULL`), then this will only work if the data is actually in UTF8.

The problem is either that your data didn't match your expectation (ie it wasn't WIN1251), or the combination of Powershell and the Firebird ODBC driver doesn't handle strings in a different character set than the console character set properly (if I'm not mistaken, the Powershell character set is utf-8).